# Control key capture set up through Chrome Remote Desktop (CRD) to Win10 running Vbox running Win10 VM

Tags: virtualbox, keymap, window-focus, chrome-remote-desktop

I have a Inception like situation. My local Win10 ( at Home) is running the CRD Apps connected to a Win 10 at work which is running in Vbox  Win 10.  I installed, in the VM Win10, SystInternals to use Zoomit and other tools. Zoomit's Live zoom key is CTRL-4.

While focused on a VM Win 10 window I press CTRL+4  and my local Zoomit actives and zoom the entire monitor not just the VM Win 10 Panel.

I cannot change the VM Live Zoom key in Zoomit because it needs you to press a control character.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I punted and changed the Local host Live Zoom to another Ctrl key and the CTRL+4 is sent and the VM Windows does zoom correctly.

This still leaves me all the other possible keys that may overlap between Local host and VM OS.
Is there key focus controls in CRD that can solve this?